# Constructor not found exception

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, missingmethodexception

I can’t understand how to fix that. Basically I can’t get instance of that class only on few clients. I was able to get an instance by using Reflection and dynamically invoke constructor. Has anyone encountered that problem before?

```
        private static void Instance()
        {
            try
            {
                var bot = new TelegramBotClient("YourToken", (HttpClient) null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
            TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = new
                TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
            Debug.Listeners.Add(myWriter);

            var type = typeof(TelegramBotClient);
            foreach (var constructor in type.GetConstructors())
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", constructor.GetParameters().Select(e => e.Name)));
            Instance();
            
        }
```

[image: Exception]

```
Output:
token,httpClient
token,webProxy

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Tele
gram.Bot.TelegramBotClient..ctor(System.String, System.Net.Http.HttpClient)'.
   at CC_Watcher.Program.Instance()
   at CC_Watcher.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Please provide both the code and the error as *text* in your question rather than as links to pictures. It's really hard to reproduce an issue from pictures - we'd basically have to type in all the code ourselves, when you've already *got* that code ready to provide us with a [mcve]...

Comment: Can you put the complete code in your question? Not as an image but as a text.

Comment: I would start by using some decompiler to check the if the actual method is available. A likely problem is that different versions of the dll is used.

Comment: I’ve already tried and method(constructor) is there. As you can see I’ve already printed out all constructors and is even possible to initialize the class through it. I’m seriously confused.

Comment: I still didn’t find a way to make it work normally. So I decided to leave it with reflection. If anyone can help me, would be appreciated.

Comment: I have just experienced the same error, because I was using telegram.bot version 17.0.0 which has dependencies on .NETCore, while my app was on .NETFramework. Downgrading to 16.0.2 resolved this issue